# Cant ping from WAN to LAN, any ideas where i have gone wrong

Tags: networking, wifi

I could do with some help.
I have a Pi with three connections:

eth0 (Internet connect) from the internet router
eth1 (LAN) 192.168.13.20 - 192.168.13.240
wlan0 (WiFi) 192.168.14.20 - 192.168.14.240

I've managed to get it so I can go on the internet through the WAN from the LAN connection and from the WiFi connection
**I can ping devices from the LAN to the WiFi but I cannot ping back from the WiFi to the LAN (ie hit devices LAN side from the WiFi)
One of the devices on the LAN exposes a port 80 setup page and I was unable to load that from a WiFi connected device**

I've tried adding rules in rules.v4 like below but they did not work

```
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

My settings are as follows:

```
    dhcpcd.conf
    ------------
    interface eth1
    metric 405
    static ip_address=192.168.13.254/24
    static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
    
    interface wlan0
    static ip_address=192.168.14.254/24
    static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
    nohook wpa_supplicant

    dnsmasq.conf
    ------------
    domain=gateway.local
    interface=eth1
    bind-dynamic
    domain-needed
    bogus-priv
    dhcp-range=192.168.13.20,192.168.13.240,255.255.255.0,24h
    
    interface=wlan0
    bind-dynamic
    domain-needed
    bogus-priv
    dhcp-range=192.168.14.20,192.168.14.240,255.255.255.0,24h

    /etc/iptables/rules.v4
    ------------
    *nat
    :PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
    :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
    :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
    -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
    COMMIT
    *filter
    -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
    COMMIT

    
    hostapd.conf
    ------------
    interface=wlan0
    country_code=GB
    ssid=Gateway
    hw_mode=g
    channel=7
    macaddr_acl=0
    auth_algs=1
    ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
    wpa=2
    wpa_passphrase=abcd
    wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    wpa_pairwise=CCMP
    rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```